# AttributeError: module 'pandas.compat' has no attribute 'iteritems'

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, pandas-ml

I am trying to import **pandas-ml** but I get this import error.
What might be the issue?

````
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-fd3c3c034481> in <module>
----> 1 import pandas_ml as pml

AttributeError: module 'pandas.compat' has no attribute 'iteritems' ```
````

Comment: How do you import it?

Comment: I just import import pandas_ml, it depends on pandas

Answer (score 1):

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas_ml/core/accessor.py", line 81, in _update_method_mapper
    for key, class_dict in compat.iteritems(cls._method_mapper):
AttributeError: module 'pandas.compat' has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

I have the same error too with python3.7. I solved it with changing `iteritems()` to `items()` .

There are two lines on accessor.py under @classmethod, change them into:

```
 for key, class_dict in cls._method_mapper.items():
'
'
'
      class_dict = {k: getattr(cls, m) for k, m in class_dict.items()}
```

For my version,
I have also encounter another import error `ImportError: cannot import name 'range' from 'pandas.compat'`in File `"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas_ml/confusion_matrix/stats.py"`. just delete `from pandas.compat import range` would do.

Reference:

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/commit/e26e2dfe6e93922830fb5fb7868b87238b85911a#diff-21f71fbdb0d3dfa55dc948e2ddcddc92

Comment: @kongkip If my answer was helpful, pls accept it - click on the check mark (✓) beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filler in. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `iteritems` attribute for `pandas.compat` appears to be have been removed recently, as [seen here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/commit/e26e2dfe6e93922830fb5fb7868b87238b85911a#diff-21f71fbdb0d3dfa55dc948e2ddcddc92) (tip from this [source](https://github.com/pandas-ml/pandas-ml/issues/124#issuecomment-524146845)).

In other words, your current version of `pandas` is incompatible with `pandas-ml` currently.

The GitHub issue suggests to maybe downgrade your `pandas` version.

```
# Installed using pip
pip install pandas==0.24.2

# Installed using conda
conda install pandas==0.24.2
```

You can run the following in the Python REPL to double check the `pandas` package version to see if it is greater than `0.25.0`.

```py
import pandas

print(pandas.__version__)
```

Comment: This is not work in my case. I was running pandas 0.25.1, and got the same error as the original post, then downgraded to pandas 0.24.2, but the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I found out, that pandas_ml is not compatible with the current verions of scikit-learn and pandas.
So I wrote a fix and made a pull request on github.
Have a look here  https://github.com/AlfredoCubitos/pandas-ml or here https://github.com/pandas-ml/pandas-ml/pull/132.